# Which type of timestamp is this and how to convert?

Tags: gps, timestamp

I have some values as follow:

```
Time stamp= 46545775926
GPS TIME(S)= 1037863153
GPS TIME(US)=841354
```

I don't know which type of timestamp the time stamp is.How can I convert GPS TIME(S) and GPS TIME(US) to this time stamp format or the reverse?

Comment: why dont you ask the data provider?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is GPS time. (S) is number of seconds since Jan 6 1980, + leap seconds. (US) is number of microseconds.